# Using CORS header filter with dropwizard 0.7.0

Tags: java, filter, jersey, cors, dropwizard

I am trying to get a dropwizard 0.7.0 (Jersey) REST service to send HTML CORS header like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I found various tutorials and also learned about the difference how to do it in 0.7.0 and the previous version. The most promising way seems to be the one [described in the dropwizard group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/dropwizard-user/ybDOTOxjlLI/tpmp3CtEu78J) but when I use the given code, no headers are sent whatsoever. The filter does not seem to be working. When I use a custom filter, it is being initialized but not used as well. Nothing unusual in the log so far.

This is my (latest) run method:

```
        @Override
public void run(BackendConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

    // XXX why doesn't this work?
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*"); // allowed origins comma separated
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD");
    filter.setInitParameter("preflightMaxAge", "5184000"); // 2 months
    filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");


    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "h2");

    environment.jersey().register(new UserResource(jdbi));
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From CrossOriginFilter:

```
    String origin = request.getHeader(ORIGIN_HEADER);
    // Is it a cross origin request ?
    if (origin != null && isEnabled(request))
```

You have to send Origin header in request to make filter working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After [reading up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) once more on the topic I think I also understand the concept now :)